# How to improve an arduino TMP36 temperature reading?

Tags: c++, performance, arduino, floating-point, sensors

The Arduino love-o-meter project (present in the starter kit) uses a `float` to compute the temperature from the voltage read from the TMP36.

The Arduino Uno microcontroller (ATmega328P) doesn't have any [FPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit) and the computation doesn't have good performance.

How can we improve this computation?

```cpp
// Code for 5V at the input of the TMP36
int reading = analogRead(PIN);
float voltage = (reading * 500.0) / 1024.0;  
float celciusTemperature = voltage - 50.0;
```

Comment: I think it would be more useful to replace the [precision] tag with a language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of bad performance is the usage of floating point values.

I will show how to get rid of it.

First we talk about precision:

- The TMP36 has a range of 500°C (from -50°C to +450°C).
- The analog read works on 10 bits from 0 to 1023 (1024 possible values).

So the precision is 500/1024. Roughly 0.5 °C.

So if we want to code the temperature on an `int`, the less significant bit of this `int` needs to code for 0.5°C instead of 1°C.

**Example:**

```cpp
int celciusTemperatureByHalfDegree = +40; // +20.0°C
int celciusTemperatureByHalfDegree = +41; // +20.5°C
int celciusTemperatureByHalfDegree = -10; // -5.0°C
int celciusTemperatureByHalfDegree = -15; // -5.5°C
```

We see that:

```cpp
celciusTemperatureByHalfDegree = celciusTemperature * 2
```

Roughly will have:

```cpp
int reading = analogRead(PIN);
int voltage = (reading * 500) / 1024;  
int celciusTemperature = voltage - 50;
int celciusTemperatureByHalfDegree = celciusTemperature * 2;
```

At this point an overflow and rounding issues cause this code to be useless.

Let's simplify it:

```cpp
int reading = (analogRead(PIN) * 500) / 1024;
int celciusTemperatureByHalfDegree = (reading - 50) * 2;
```

And again:

```cpp
int reading = (analogRead(PIN) * 500) / 512;
int celciusTemperatureByHalfDegree = reading - 100;
```

And again:

```cpp
int reading = (analogRead(PIN) * 125) / 128;
int celciusTemperatureByHalfDegree = reading - 100;
```

At this point there is no more rounding issue. But `analogRead()` gives an output between 0 and 1023.

And `1023 * 125` is bigger than max `int16` (32,767), so overflow is possible.

Here we will use that 125 = 5*25 and 128 = 4*32.

```cpp
int reading = (analogRead(PIN) * 5 * 25) / (4 * 32);
int celciusTemperatureByHalfDegree = reading - 100;
```

Will become:

```cpp
int reading = analogRead(PIN); // 0 to 1023
reading *= 5;                  // 0 to 5115 (no overflow)
reading /= 4;                  // 0 to 1278 (no overflow)
reading *= 25;                 // 0 to 31950 (no overflow)
reading /= 32;                 // 0 to 998
int celciusTemperatureByHalfDegree = reading - 100;
```

Finally to print it we will use this code:

```cpp
// print the integer value of the temperature
Serial.print(celciusTemperatureByHalfDegree/2);
Serial.print(".");
// less significant bit code for "__.0" of "__.5"
Serial.print(celciusTemperatureByHalfDegree % 2 ? '5' : '0'); 
Serial.print("°C");
```

Comment: As per the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/TMP35_36_37.pdf), the TMP36 has a range of -40 thru +125 celsius.

Comment: @starfry This is equivalent to a range of 340 useful digital values (over 1024). Nevertheless, 340x125 > 32767 and this doesn't solve the overflow issue.